# Bootstrap modal's position is incorrect

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a few modals on my website all of them have the same HTML code, same styles and everything is 100% identical. But in this modal I have problem with its position, modal is a little bit lower and a little bit left. I included a screenshot of the actual modal.

I have tried to compare everything from this modal with other modals on my website and everything is identical.

```
<div id="myModal" id="darkModalForm" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is a screenshot of actual problem:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to the website? So I can not help you.

Comment: @QJan84 Can I give you any more information? What else do you need?